# How to click the menu item from the application using pywinauto

Tags: python-3.7, pywinauto

```
import pywinauto,time
from pywinauto import Application
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import ButtonWrapper
from pywinauto import mouse
app = Application().start(cmd_line="C:\\Users\\6141\\Desktop\\eval\\32bit\\ProSeriesLauncher.exe")
time.sleep(20)
pywinauto.mouse.click(button="left",coords=(1275,270))
time.sleep(20)
app.ProSeriesLauncher.MenuSelect("File->Open Client").click()

**Error occurs:**
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError: Could not find 'ProSeriesLauncher' in 'dict_keys([])'
```

This application has a menu "file" where there is Open Client I need to open by click. Is there any method Application name: ProSeries Basic.

Comment: Maybe launcher spawns a child process. So you need to connect the application object by title. Title can be found using `print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="win32").windows()])` or use `backend="uia"` which can see more detailed elements on some apps.